# SQL query for specific use case

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# Create a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Convert to Spark DataFrame").getOrCreate()

# Define the data
data = [
    ('AB123', '05:10', 'PANDIAN', '3A', 'CHN', 'MAD', 'CNF'),
    ('AB123', '05:15', 'PANDIAN', '2S', 'CHN', 'MAD', 'RAC'),
    ('AB123', '05:20', 'PANDIAN', '2S', 'CHN', 'MAD', 'CNF'),
    ('CA123', '06:15', 'PKK', '2S', 'MAD', 'TRC', 'RAC'),
    ('CA123', '06:20', 'PKK', '2S', 'MAD', 'TRC', 'CNF'),
    ('CA123', '06:30', 'PKK', 'IA', 'MAD', 'TRC', 'CNF'),
    ('DE123', '07:20', 'MDRD', '2S', 'MAD', 'YVD', 'CNF'),
    ('DE123', '07:30', 'MDRD', '2S', 'MAD', 'YVD', 'RAC')
]

# Create a Spark DataFrame from the data
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=['session', 'time', 'train', 'bkg_cls', 'board', 'depart', 'response'])

# Show the DataFrame
df.createOrReplaceTempView('traininfo')
```

From this i want to extract the record, which has RAC/ other response first for same train and in the same session then it got confirmed. But i don't want to extract the record where the ticket is confirm in the session first then RAC.

Expected output:

```
session,time,train,bkg_cls,board,depart
CA123,06:20,PKK,2S,MAD,TRC,CNF
```

Explanation -> Session CA123 has RAC response first and then CNF in next transaction so same is captured.

Whereas in Session AB123 first transaction is confirmed so  irrespective of BKG_CLS 2S is RAC to CNF we are ignoring that.

Also DE123 is also excluded because first transaction is confirmed for that train.

Comment: Any reason why [CA123,06:20] is expected in the output, but [''CA123', '06:30'] aren't expected in the output?

Comment: Yes, because there is one CNF is recorded. So 6.30 is not expected

Comment: so to confirm my understanding is correct, if there is more than one CNF after RAC in the same session, we only pick the one right after RAC. Is that right?

Comment: That is Correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Spark SQL window function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-window.html) in multiple steps to get the result you want.

1. Use window function to find how many NON-CNF responses after current row with a session.
2. Use window function to find all sessions has NON-CNF response after CFN response.
3. Filter all sessions with non-CNF response after CFN response and all rows has NON-CNF rsponse after, rank the rest within session and pick earlist CNF response.

Here is the [query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a7f76f/14):

```
with traininfo_with_non_cnf_marker AS (
select
    *,
    sum(case when response <> 'CNF' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by session order by time desc) num_non_cnf_after 
from
    traininfo
),
traininfo_with_cnf_after_non_cnf_marker AS ( 
select
    *,
    sum(case when response='CNF' and num_non_cnf_after> 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by session) as session_num_cnf_after_non_cnf
from
    traininfo_with_non_cnf_marker
),
traininfo_qualified_row AS (
select
     *,
     row_number() over (partition by session order by time) as row_num
from
    traininfo_with_cnf_after_non_cnf_marker
where
    session_num_cnf_after_non_cnf = 0 and num_non_cnf_after=0 and response = 'CNF'
)
select
    session,
    time,
    train,
    bkg_cls,
    board,
    depart,
    response
from
    traininfo_qualified_row
where
    row_num =1
```

| session | time | train | bkg_cls | board | depart | response |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CA123 | 06:20 | PKK | 2S | MAD | TRC | CNF |

Answer (score 0):

We can simplify by separate CNF vs Non-CNF cases and then join CNF time > Non-CNF time

```
df_res = spark.sql("""
    with non_cnf as (
      select session, 
             time,
             train,
             bkg_cls,
             board,
             depart
             from traininfo
            where response <> 'CNF'
    ),
    cnf as(
      select * from (
      select session, 
             time,
             train,
             bkg_cls,
             board,
             depart,
             row_number() over(partition by session, train, board, depart order by time) as rn
             from traininfo
            where response = 'CNF' ) a 
            where a.rn = 1
    )
    select cnf.*
    from cnf 
    join non_cnf nc
    on cnf.session = nc.session
    and cnf.train = nc.train
    and cnf.bkg_cls = nc.bkg_cls
    and cnf.board = nc.board
    and cnf.depart = nc.depart
    and cnf.time > nc.time

""")

df_res.show(20,False)


+-------+-----+-----+-------+-----+------+---+
|session|time |train|bkg_cls|board|depart|rn |
+-------+-----+-----+-------+-----+------+---+
|CA123  |06:20|PKK  |2S     |MAD  |TRC   |1  |
+-------+-----+-----+-------+-----+------+---+
```